# Can you use multiple mutex lock/unlock with non-identical keys within the same function to calculate average in a data structure?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, mutex

Say I wanted to compute the average of the values in an **array X of size N**. Let's assume that we use **T threads where T is some fraction of N** so we are multithreading.

Is it possible to declare two unique mutex keys and execute the following without error?

Edit: any ideas on how to go about computing something like an average, maximum, minimum, etc.?

See below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* sum(void* arg);

int sum = 0;
int average = 0;

int x[N];

int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t threads[T];

    for(i=0; i<T; i++)
        pthread_create(&x[i], NULL, sum, (void *)i);
    for(i=0; i<T; i++)
        pthread_join(x[i], NULL);
}

void* sum(void* arg)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int *id = (int *) arg;

    pthread_mutex_t key1;
    pthread_mutex_t key2;

    int size = N/T;
    int start = id * size;
    int end = id * size + size;

    for(i=start; i<end; i++)
    {
        counter = counter + x[i];
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&key1);
    sum += counter;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&key1);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&key2);
    average = sum / counter;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&key2);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Not only did you give each thread its own private pair of mutexes (See David's answer below for why that's wrong), but you also make them all share one `sum`.  That is an equally bad idea because the threads will spend all their time in contention for the shared `sum`.  It probably will be _slower_ than just using a single thread.  What you should do instead is have each thread compute its own _partial_ sum over its portion of the data, and then when they're done, have the main thread add the partials up to get the final sum and compute the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a disaster. Each thread will call `sum` and they will each get their own mutex. That means one thread can lock its `key2` at the same time another thread locks its `key2`. So the two threads could access `average` at the same time.

You need one, and only one, mutex to protect `average`. Otherwise, it's not actually protected.

(Also, you have both a function and a global called `sum`. That will lead to pain and confusion.)

You also have another problem. Each thread is taking the shared `sum` and dividing it by its private `counter`. That doesn't make any sense at all. The `sum` variable needs to be divided by the total number of entries it sums to get an average, not the number of entries added by that particular thread.

I would suggest two changes:

1. Have only one mutex. Make it a global.
2. Don't have the `sum` function touch the `average` variable. After you've joined all the threads, just do `average = sum / N;`.

Comment: what if after **pthread_mutex_unlock(&key1);** I called **new_sum = sum** and then in the second mutex called **average = new_sum / counter;**

Comment: I don't see how that's any different. The problem is that each thread has its own `key1` and its own `key2`. So the mutexes won't actually synchronize across the threads because they're not shared.

Comment: so you'd want to only use that one key, **key1** as in replace **key2**

Comment: @ConnorBrereton No, because then you will still have too many mutexes. I'm suggesting only having *one* mutex, not one for each instance of `counter`. (Do you understand that your code creates far more than two mutexes?)

Comment: no I don't understand how the original code is creating more than 2. if you're willing to explain further id really appreciate it. you've been a great help so far

Comment: @ConnorBrereton Okay, and so each thread has its own `counter`, right? So doesn't each thread also have its own `key1` and `key2`?